# How to increase the number of expressions limit in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am fairly new to snowflake, and I am trying to query and get the records of some 200,000 IDs/rows. But unfortunately the snowflake has a limit where the user can't put more than 16000 expressions in the list.
My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
APP_ID
,APP_DT
FROM table 
WHERE APP_ID IN 
(
....
,...
,...
,...
.
.
.
.
,...
)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a list of APP_IDs from someone in an excel, and this is the only way I could use the list to fetch information (WHERE IN - filter). But snowflake is also restricting me. Kindly let me know if there is way to temporary expand the upper limit so that I can download the data locally for all 200,000 app IDs at once. I tried making CTE/permanent tables but that's not changing the error.
[image]

Any comment/help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Put those values in a separate (temporary) table. JOIN, or do IN.

Comment: actually, creating temporary tables is also generating the same error,

Comment: To @jarlh's point, if the in clause won't work with a table either, then join the tables. A left join with the values that would otherwise go inside the in clause on the left side will do it.

Comment: The correct way to handle this is to create a table with one column and then upload all your ids into that table and write a SQL query that joins the table of ids to the main table. There is no way around the character limit for expressions. If you're saying you can't create a table then please share how exactly you are trying to do that, since it should not generate an error like that.

Answer (score 1):

Please create a table with all the ids.

In this example, I have a table with more than a million ids, and the `WHERE id IN()` works without a problem:

```sql
select count(*) from (select id from ids_table)
-- 1056343
;
select sum(wikipedia_views)
from wikidata_people_views
where id in (select id from ids_table)
-- 15863585373
;
```